# What is the difference between if string: and if string == ''

Tags: string, python-2.7, if-statement

I have recently begun coding in python 2.7.13
In my program, I have used both forms of if conditional checks to check if a string is empty or not.
But using them interchangeably fails
Could someone provide some insights.
Also is there a universal method to check for an empty string irrespective of the encoding ( ASCII, Unicode, UTF-8 etc.)

Comment: Both tests will be true for an empty string, regardless of encoding. An empty string is empty in *any codec*. One of those tests will also be false if `string` is **not a string**.

Comment: The second is false for `string = None`.